# Prevent element selection on dblClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm working on an "edit in place".
No problem for coding this, but i have some visual issues.

When i double click on the element i want to edit, some "elements" are selected, before the input field is shown.

I handle the dblclick event with a `event.preventDefault()`.
I tried the `stopPropagation()` too but nothing to do..

Maybe i have to handle this with CSS.

Could you help me?

[image]

Comment: `.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}`

Comment: On what kind of elements are you clicking?